# C# to VB conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, listbox, c#-to-vb.net

Check the following link..

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/197335/Synchronized-ListBox-objects-or-how-to-scroll-2-Li

Its a code to synchronize two listboxes.. The code is in C#.. Converted most of the things to VB but I am not understanding how to convert the following lines..

1 - private const int SIF_ALL = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS;

2 - if (OnHorizontalScroll != null)

3 - if (OnVerticalScroll != null)

PS : In the second and third statements, OnHorizontalScroll and OnVerticalScroll are events created by me!

Comment: sorry.. edited and added link..

Comment: What dont you understnad on how to convert the if? I think the `null is Nothing` in vb.

Comment: Don't the '|' in #1 need to be replaced with 'Or' in VB?

Comment: but it is an event and it gives an error when I write
'If Not OnHorizontalScroll Is Nothing Then'

Comment: the 'Or' error is gone..!! Had done same thing but a small typo error was giving an error..!!

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a code converter tool to convert lines of code between C# and VB.Net

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Just copy and paste the code you want and it usually works great.

Here is the output I get:

1) Private Const SIF_ALL As Integer = SIF_RANGE Or SIF_PAGE Or SIF_POS Or SIF_TRACKPOS

2) If OnHorizontalScroll IsNot Nothing
   You don't actually need this line in VB.  Whatever the next line was, just write this...
   RaiseEvent OnHorizontalScroll( ... )

3) If OnVerticalScroll IsNot Nothing
   You don't actually need this line in VB.  Whatever the next line was, just write this...
   RaiseEvent OnHorizontalScroll( ... )

Comment: Second and third are correct **SYNTACTICALLY** but not **LOGICALLY**..

Comment: The error is
**Public Event OnVerticalScroll(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.**

Comment: Yep.  Checking for a null event is not necessary in VB.  Just raise the event.  Basically, that line of code has no equivalent in VB.Net.  I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the code should look in VB

```
Private Const SIF_ALL As Integer = SIF_RANGE Or SIF_PAGE Or SIF_POS Or SIF_TRACKPOS
If OnHorizontalScroll IsNot Nothing
If OnVerticalScroll IsNot Nothing
```

Online converter from Telerik
http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1):

Don´t understand why one would want to convert anything from C# to VB but here it goes;

**1.** `private const int SIF_ALL = SIF_RANGE Or SIF_PAGE Or SIF_POS Or SIF_TRACKPOS;`

**2.** `if (OnHorizontalScroll IsNot Nothing)`

**3.** `if (OnVerticalScroll IsNot Nothing)`

For reference, see [VB.NET and C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html).

Comment: Second and third are correct **SYNTACTICALLY** but not **LOGICALLY**..

Comment: The error is
**Public Event OnVerticalScroll(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.**